# I want to allocate the unused disk space to ubuntu. How to do it?

Tags: partitioning

I was dual booting with Windows and Ubuntu before. And now I uninstalled Windows using os-uninstaller in Ubuntu. I want to move all the free space to `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7`. Please help me out?

[image: Disk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **This is risky and you need a good and current backup**, at least of your personal files, if possible also of the whole system, for example a compressed image file by Clonezilla. This file should be stored in another drive (an external drive), which is not connected during the partitioning work.
2. I think the best way would be to backup all your personal files and after that make a fresh installation of Ubuntu. After installation you can restore your personal files.
3. I think the second best way is to keep your home directory, and modify the fresh installation by selecting it via **Something else** at the partitioning windows of the installer. If you leave unallocated drive space next to the home partition, you can 'grow' it afterwards (increase its size).
4. Or you can try to keep the Ubuntu system as it is, and use the former Windows partitions as data partitions for Ubuntu. But since the root partition of Ubuntu is almost full, you would want to move its head end (the left end as illustrated by gparted). And it means that the bootloader will be confused, and you have to reinstall the bootloader, *grub2*. This can be done according to this link: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing). Now that you know how the bootloader must and can be re-installed, you can
5. Remove the ntfs partitions
6. Grow the extended partition (move it's left boundary) to use all the unallocated space
7. Move the root partition to the left end of the extended partition
8. Execute these changes (click the check symbol in gparted)
9. Reinstall the bootloader

If this works, fine. Next you can

9. Grow the root partition and the home partition from each side in order to use the unallocated space between them.
10. Execute these changes (click the check symbol in gparted)

If this works, fine. You did it :-)

-o-

If something went wrong, you need to restore your system or make a fresh installation and restore your personal data into it. **You must be ready to use the backup**.

Comment: I think fresh installation will be a good idea. How to do it?

Comment: Do you mean a fresh installation of the whole drive? Or 'only' a fresh installation of Ubuntu and keeping the partition table? - A fresh installation of the whole drive is simple, let Ubuntu use the whole drive, and it will overwrite whatever was on the drive. This means that everything that was on the drive will be lost, so you had better backup all important files before you start installing.

Comment: I will do a fresh installation of the whole drive. Ubuntu is enough, very cool :)

Comment: I wish you good luck :-)